# Search results not updating after second search - REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I set up a search bar, and after I search the results will pop up. However, the issue is, if I don't refresh the page and search again, it will push me to the new search, but the search results won't update with it. Why would the updated param be showing even though the results aren't updating?

Ex. first url is search/erl,second url is search/Groovy%20Playlist

First search

[image: First search]

Second search, query param updated, but search results didn't

[image: Second search]

Searchbar.js

```
class SearchBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {query: '', results: [], isLoading: false}
  }

  componentWillMount() {
     this.resetComponent()
   }

   resetComponent = () => this.setState({ isLoading: false, results: [], query: '' })

   search(query) {
     this.setState({ query });
     axios
       .get(`/api/search?query=${query}`)
       .then(response => {
         this.setState({ results: response.data});
       })
       .catch(error => console.log(error));
   }

   handleFormSubmit = () => {
   console.log('search:', this.state.query);
   this.props.action
   this.props.history.push(`/search/${this.state.query}`)
   this.resetComponent()



 }


  handleInputChange = (query) => {
    this.search(query);
    this.setState({ isLoading: true, query })

    setTimeout(() =>
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
      }) , 300)

  }

  handleResultSelect = (e, { result }) => this.setState({ query: result.title}  )

  render () {

    const resultRenderer = ({ title }) => <List content = {title}/>
    return (

      <Form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
      <Search
        loading={this.state.isLoading}
        onResultSelect={this.handleResultSelect}
        onSearchChange={(event) => {this.handleInputChange(event.target.value)}}
        showNoResults={false}
        value={this.state.query}
        resultRenderer={resultRenderer}
        results ={this.state.results}
        type={"submit"}
        { ...this.props}  />
      </Form>

    );
  }

}


export default withRouter (SearchBar)
```

Search.js

```
class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      results: []
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    const { match: { params } } = this.props;
    axios
      .get(`/api/search?query=${params.query}`)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({ results: response.data });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }


    render() {
         console.log(this.state.results)
      return(

        <div>
          <div className = "heading centered">
            <h1> Search results for: {this.props.match.params.query} </h1>
          </div>
          {this.state.results.map((post) => {
            return(
                <Post key = {post.id} post={post}/>

            )
          })}
        </div>
      );

    }
}

export default Search
```

Comment: I guess `this.setState({ query });` inside `search` should be `this.setState({ query, redults: [] });`

Comment: And you should definetly either query in the search bar or in the search itself, but not inside both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating `results` of the SearchBars state will be passed down to Search's props, but you don't work with `this.props.results` but rather with `this.state.results`, and that doesnt get  updated even if the props change. That works the first time as you reload the Search's state inside `componentWillMount` but that doesnt get called again as the component is not remounted. Therefore Search always works with its states results, that are never updated.

Now to solve this chaos, remove the `componentWillMount` logic from Search as that is actually doing what SearchBar already does, and add a listener to `componentWillReceiveProps` that updates the Searches state, or don't work with the state at all inside Search but take the passed in results instead as `this.props.results`.

```
  const Search = ({ match, results }) => (
    <div>
      <div className = "heading centered">
        <h1> Search results for: {match.params.query} </h1>
      </div>
      {results.map((post) => 
            <Post key = {post.id} post={post}/>
      )}
   </div>
  );
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. I understand that the componentWillMount is only mounting once. That makes sense. How would I go about setting a listener with component will receive props. I know what to do once I get the props. I just don't know how to get them after the page is pushed.

Comment: @alex actually in this case Search shouldnt keep its own state.